# Popular Flash Games on Stream

Tags: flash

I am interested where I can find list of popular flash games, just to know it's posibilities. Are there popular flash games on stream?

Comment: I assume you mean Steam? Flash games can be distributed on Steam but I can't think of any off the top of my head.

Comment: I found http://store.steampowered.com/app/40700/?snr=1_5_9__13 only this one. I just wont to know if it is possible with new acceleration abilities to make valuable 2d flash game maybe platformer

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: i know : Defender's Quest: Valley of the Forgotten ; incredipede ; machinarium and the binding of isaac

Comment: Super Meat Boy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Steam, but here's a list of websites where you can find popular Flash games:

1. **[ArmorGames](http://armorgames.com/)**
2. [Newgrounds](http://www.newgrounds.com/game/)
3. **[Kongregate](http://www.kongregate.com/top-rated-games)**
4. **[Andkon](http://www.andkon.com/arcade/)**<sup>1</sup>
5. [Mochimedia](http://www.mochimedia.com/games/)<sup>2</sup>
6. [jmtb02](http://jmtb02.com/games/)
7. **[MiniClip](http://www.miniclip.com/games/en/)**
8. **[Crazy Monkey Games](http://crazymonkeygames.com/)**

Note that the ones in bold also offer sponsorships for games, which may interest you. Sponsorships are how I made 10x the money during high school that my friends were making working at McDonalds.

<sup>1</sup> Andkon doesn't really offer sponsorships, they just offer small amounts of money for a branded version of your game to be hosted on their website. Nice guy there.

<sup>2</sup> Mochimedia offers a service that places advertisements on the loading screen of your game. I still rack up >$50 a month from my old games being played up to 3 years down the track.